# How to change the title alignment just for the appendix sections?

Tags: latex

I am formatting my dissertation document using a class usfdis.cls from http://dalamagkidis.info/miscellanea/usfdis/. However due to new specifications, the Appendices titles should now be Single-space and aligned to the left margin.

The code referred to the appendix section in the usfdis.cls is the following:

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{% Appendices have a cover page and different
                 % layout
\clearpage
\vspace*{0.6in}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Appendices}}
 \begin{center}{\chpsformat Appendices\par}
 \end{center}
 \newpage
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2\baselineskip+3pt} %<--- Weird 3.5pt
\setlength{\headsep}{2\baselineskip-3pt}%            it's magic!
\ch@ngetext
\gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname }%
\gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapter}
{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}\@afterindentfalse\secdef\@appendix\@schapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\makeatletter
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\def\@oddhead{\vbox{\chapalign\chpformat (continued) } }
\makeatother

}
```

One option is to put the appendices as sections instead of Chapters and then they are going to be aligned to the left but I need also to have the section titles as for example: Appendix A: Name of Appendix A Appendix B: Name of Appendix B, etc